# Multiple Definition of "..." c

Tags: c++, header

I have a header file "USpecs.h":

```
#ifndef USPECS_H
#define USPECS_H
#include "Specs.h"


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<Specs*> UcakSpecs;


#endif
```

I am using this header both in main function and another class named Ucak.

But when i build it the following error occurs:

> Ucak.cpp|6|multiple definition of `UcakSpecs'|

As i searched before, it should be okay with #ifndef but it is not.

Comment: Please show the CPP code file

Comment: There's a typo on the first "include". Also, if this is not `Specs.h` (since you're including it), what is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The include guards only prevent multiple definitions within a single translation unit (i.e. a single source file with its included headers). They do not prevent multiple definitions when you include the header from multiple source files.

Instead, you should have a declaration in the header:

```
extern std::vector<Specs*> UcakSpecs;
```

and a definition in one (and only one) source file:

```
std::vector<Specs*> UcakSpecs;
```

Answer (score 4):

Inclusion guards only prevent the header from being included in the same translation unit more than once. If you include this header in multiple translation units, you will have multiple definitions of `UcakSpecs` across the program.

The way to declare a global variable is to declare it as `extern` in the header file:

```
#ifndef USPECS_H
#define USPECS_H
#inclde "Specs.h"


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

extern std::vector<Specs*> UcakSpecs;

#endif
```

A global variable declared as `extern` is only a declaration.

Then make sure it is only defined in a single translation unit by defining it in an implementation file (perhaps in `USpecs.cpp`);

```
std::vector<Specs*> UcakSpecs;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `#ifndef` only applies to a single compilation unit.  Since you have two (the main function and `Ucak` class), the variable is defined twice.

Consider declaring the variable as `extern` in the header file:

```
extern std::vector<Specs*> UcakSpecs;
```

and defining it inside the `Ucak.cpp` file:

```
std::vector<Specs*> UcakSpecs;
```

This should work.