# C++ program calling C Function Getting Undefined References During g++ linking

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have a simple C++ program that makes calls to a C function.  When I link the 2 object files to create the C++ executable I get a number of "Undefined Reference" errors and single "multiple references to svrport" error.  I have following files chorusmain.cpp, chorusclient.c, and chorusclient.h.  chorusmain.cpp makes the calls to functions in chorusclient.c.  chorusclient.c is very large and I wrote it 2 years ago.  I now need these functions in a C++ application and don't want to re-write in C++ and debug the code all over again.  I refactored chorusclient.c to a set of callable functions.  For simplicity, I reduced the code to just the important components.

**chorusclient.c**

```
#include <...>
#include "chorusclient.h"

int my_C_Function()
{
  ...
}
```

**chorusclient.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int my_C_Function();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**chorusmain.cpp**

```
#include <...>
#include "chorusclient.h"

int main(int argc, char *arvg[])
{
  ...
  my_C_Function();
  ...
}
```

Here is the gcc/g++ build and link commands,

```
gcc -c -o chorusclient.o chorusclient.c -I/usr/include/json-c - 
    I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include -I. -I. -lssl -lcrypto -ljson-c

g++ -c -o chorusmain.o chorusmain.cpp -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. - 
    I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 - 
    I/usr/include -I. -I. -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread

g++ -o ChorusMain chorusclient.o chorusmain.o
```

I get no errors with the first 2 gcc/g++ builds.  I get the following undefined reference errors during the g++ link,

```
debian@beaglebone:~/Projects/CloudClient$ ls
chorusclient.c  chorusclient.h  chorusclient.o  chorusmain.cpp  chorusmain.o
debian@beaglebone:~/Projects/CloudClient$ g++ -o ChorusMain chorusmain.o chorusclient.o
chorusclient.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `svrport'
chorusmain.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
chorusclient.o: In function `chorusServices':
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x408): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x416): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x41c): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_config'
chorusclient.o: In function `httpSend':
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1c2c): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1c3a): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1c4c): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1c50): undefined reference to `TLSv1_2_client_method'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1c58): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1c62): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1c7e): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1ca0): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1caa): undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1cb0): undefined reference to `SSL_connect'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1ce4): undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1cec): undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1cfa): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_oneline'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1d1a): undefined reference to `X509_get_issuer_name'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1d28): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_oneline'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1d3e): undefined reference to `X509_free'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1d4a): undefined reference to `SSL_get_current_cipher'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1d52): undefined reference to `SSL_CIPHER_get_name'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1d80): undefined reference to `SSL_write'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1d90): undefined reference to `SSL_read'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1df2): undefined reference to `SSL_read'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1e8e): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x1e9a): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
chorusclient.o: In function `jsonBatteryData':
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x21a8): undefined reference to `json_object_new_object'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x21b2): undefined reference to `json_object_new_string'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x21be): undefined reference to `json_object_new_string'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x21ca): undefined reference to `json_object_new_string'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x21d8): undefined reference to `json_object_new_double'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x21e6): undefined reference to `json_object_new_double'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x21f4): undefined reference to `json_object_new_double'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2202): undefined reference to `json_object_new_double'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2210): undefined reference to `json_object_new_double'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2220): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x222e): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x223c): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x224a): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2258): undefined reference to `json_object_object_add'
chorusclient.o:chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2266): more undefined references to `json_object_object_add' follow
chorusclient.o: In function `jsonBatteryData':
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2292): undefined reference to `json_object_to_json_string'
chorusclient.o: In function `blockencrypt':
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x22de): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x22ee): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_cbc'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x22fe): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x231a): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptUpdate'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x233c): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2354): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'
chorusclient.o: In function `decrypt':
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2370): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2380): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_cbc'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2390): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptInit_ex'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x23ac): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptUpdate'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x23ce): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex'
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x23e6): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'
chorusclient.o: In function `handleErrors':
chorusclient.c:(.text+0x2404): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
debian@beaglebone:~/Projects/CloudClient$
```

When I create a simple C program that calls chorusclient.c and I build a link I get no undefined reference errors and the program works correctly.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You list the libraries when compiling to object files; you don't list the libraries when trying to link the executable.  The libraries are not relevant while compiling object files — they are crucial when linking the executable.

Comment: Jonathan, Could you be more specific on how I should format the g++ link command?  The reason why I ask is that I have looked at multiple examples with libraries.  All of the examples link the libraries during the compile and then simply link the object files during the final link as I have done.

Comment: Can you specify a URL to any of the examples you have seen?  If you have a single source file, then you can omit the `-c` option (that stops the compilation at the object file stage) and add the libraries, and everything is done in a single command.  If you have multiple source files needed to make a single program with C and C++ compilation needed, you must have a separate linking phase (using the C++ compiler to do the linking), and that linking phase must specify the libraries. You could list the C object file with the C++ source file and the `-I` options and the libraries in a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you have:

```
gcc -c -o chorusclient.o chorusclient.c -I/usr/include/json-c \
    -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include -I. -I. -lssl -lcrypto -ljson-c
g++ -c -o chorusmain.o chorusmain.cpp -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. \
    -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 \
    -I/usr/include -I. -I. -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
g++ -o ChorusMain chorusclient.o chorusmain.o
```

You list the libraries when compiling to create the object files; you don't list the libraries when trying to link the executable.  The libraries are not relevant while creating object files — they are crucial when linking the executable.

You therefore need something more like:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -c -o chorusclient.o chorusclient.c -I/usr/include/json-c \
    -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include -I. 
g++ -Wall -Werror -c -o chorusmain.o chorusmain.cpp -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ \
    -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 \
    -I/usr/include -I.
g++ -o ChorusMain chorusclient.o chorusmain.o -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -ljson-c
```

I'm not convinced you need the `-I/usr/include`, and you often don't need the `-I.` (unless you insist on using `#include <chorusclient.h>` instead of `#include "chorusclient.h"`), and you definitely don't need `-I.` repeated.

There's a chance you need to resequence the list of libraries in the linking — it might be better to put `-lpthread` near the end.

I added the `-Wall -Werror` options because you shouldn't be trying to run your code unless it compiles cleanly under at least those options (I'd add more to my code — this is enough to make the point).

I'm a little surprised you need the `-I/usr/include/openssl` line; should you be using `#include <openssl/ssl.h>` etc (for the OpenSSL headers) so that you don't need the `-I/usr/include/openssl` command line option?  Similarly, perhaps, with the Qt and JSON-C headers?

The other problem is that you have an object — probably a global variable — called `svrport` defined in both `chorusclient.o` and `chorusmain.o`.  This means that by some mechanism or another, you have the same object defined (rather than declared) in both source files.  This might be because it is defined rather than declared in the header (but that isn't shown in the code).  Or it might be because you have it defined in both source files.  If it needs to be a global variable, it should be declared in the header and defined in one of the source files (probably `chorusclient.c` since the `chorusclient.h` header is declaring it) and not defined in the other.

Comment: Ok, I tried your recommondation and got the following error -- debian@beaglebone:~/Projects/CloudClient$ g++ -o ChorusMain chorusclient.o chorusmain.o -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -ljson-c
chorusmain.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `svrport'
chorusclient.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
debian@beaglebone:~/Projects/CloudClient$ ls
chorusclient.c  chorusclient.h  chorusclient.o  chorusmain.cpp  chorusmain.o
debian@beaglebone:~/Projects/CloudClient$  Sorry for the poor formating.  Formatting is not allowed in comments.

Comment: Yes, formatting isn't allowed in comments. It can be a nuisance. It appears there's a bug in your `chorusclient.c` and `chorusmain.cpp` code such that the object (global variable?) `svrport` is defined in both object files.  Since you've not shown the variable, it isn't possible to say what you're doing wrong, but I'd not be surprised to find it was defined in the header (or, failing that, both files separately define it). It is, however, unrelated to the undefined references — it appears that your missing symbols have 'all' been satisfied. (I admit I overlooked the multiple definition error.)

Comment: It looks like your suggestion is on the right path.  I agree with your assertion that I have an error.  I am getting some warnings during the compile.  I did not get the errors a year ago the last time I compiled this code.  These seem to be coming from a newer version of gcc/g++ that does not like the syntax of some of my strings.  Let me study this further and see what I find.

Comment: Ok, I cleaned up my C code warnings.  I also found an incorrect "const" definition in chorusclient.h -- had "unsigned short svrport = 8443" changed to "const unsigned short svrport = 8443".  This was correct for "C" but not when linking to a C++ object file and causes multiple definitions.  I removed "-I/usr/include" and and "-I." and the extra "-I." as Jonathan recommended.  Everything now compiles and links correctly. So, Jonathan suggestion of placing the libraries in the g++ link and eliminating extra library references was absolutely correct.

Comment: My multiple references to svrport was due to a not so good declaration of svrport in chorusclient.h.  Works ok in C but not in C++.  Had "unsigned short svrport = 8443".  Changed to "const unsigned short svrport = 8443" and no longer get the multiple references See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765529/multiple-definition-of-c

Comment: Note that this worked because you have only one C file using the header.  If you had multiple C files using the header, you'd be back into multiple-definition problems.  C++ treats `const unsigned short svrport = 8443;` as local to the source file (in C terms, as a `static`); C treats it as a 'regular' global constant variable (almost, but not quite, a contradiction in terms).  To make it work in C with multiple files, you'd want to consider `static const unsigned short svrport = 8443;` in the header, but that's not strictly idiomatic C++ (the `static` isn't needed, but it does compile OK).